# Error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext when test in JUnit run

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I am having problems with the execution of Unitary Test with JUnit. The application is made with Spring Boot and Java with the JDK 8 version. When I run the Test it shows me the error **"Error loading ApplicationContext when launching a test with JUnit"**

```java
package com.dev.loyaltyservice.loyalty.transaction.unit;

import com.dev.loyaltyservice.loyalty.transaction.domain.ActivityType;
import com.dev.loyaltyservice.loyalty.transaction.infrastructure.dataproviders.bus.ActivityIdentificationSelector;
import com.dev.loyaltyservice.loyalty.transaction.infrastructure.dataproviders.bus.response.OriginInfo;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ActivityIdentifierTest {
    private static final String identificationCustom1 = "123124";
    private static final String identificationCustom2 = "AABBCC00";
    private static final BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(1);
    private static final BigDecimal totalRefunds = new BigDecimal(-1);

    @Test
    public void it_should_return_custom1_value_when_is_refund_tpv() {
        String activityIdentifierCustom1 = "123124";

        OriginInfo.Activity activity = new OriginInfo.Activity(
                "",
                totalRefunds, "", 0, 0, 0, 0, activityIdentifierCustom1, null);

        String actualIdentification = ActivityIdentificationSelector.getIdentificationFrom(ActivityType.REFUND_TPV, activity);

        Assert.assertEquals(identificationCustom1, actualIdentification);
    }

    @Test
    public void it_should_return_custom2_value_when_is_refund_web() {
        String activityIdentifierCustom1 = "1231241";
        String activityIdentifierCustom2 = "AABBCC00";
        OriginInfo.Activity activity = new OriginInfo.Activity(
                "",
                totalRefunds, "", 0, 0, 0, 0, activityIdentifierCustom1,     activityIdentifierCustom2);

        String actualIdentification = ActivityIdentificationSelector.getIdentificationFrom(ActivityType.REFUND_WEB, activity);

        Assert.assertEquals(identificationCustom2, actualIdentification);
    }
}
```

The error that shows me is the following: Error executing the test ¿Does anyone know what may be happening?

Thank you very much, Regards

Comment: The "Error loading ApplicationContext when launching a test with JUnit" will have a lengthy stacktrace, at the bottom of which should be a "Caused by" giving you a better idea of the cause. If you can't figure it out, please add the final "Caused by" to your post

Comment: Please provide full log stacktrace for the exception.